# How to check network connection within ViewGroup Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

So im just trying to check my network connection and perform executions if it is true or false. I know within a fragment you can use the getactivity before get system service, however this does not work for me? Thanks for the help :)

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView textView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);
```

---

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =(ConnectivityManager).getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected())
        {
            textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            Byron.setEnabled(false);
            Lennox.setEnabled(false);
            Skenners.setEnabled(false);
            Ballina.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside ViewGroup you can use getContext() method for getting system Service.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =(ConnectivityManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a init() function in all constructor of you custom view/viewgroup like this:

```
public class CustomView extends Button {
    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // Other stuffs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate class in your project AppUtil like this:

```
public class AppUtil{
public static boolean isNetworkConnectionAvailable(Context ctx, boolean showDialog){
        ConnectivityManager manager =(ConnectivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        if(!isConnected&&showDialog){
            AppUtil.showSimpleDialog(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.network_not_available),
                    ctx.getString(R.string.internet_not_available));
        }
        return isConnected;
    }

}
```

To check the network connectivity proceed like this:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView textView;

if (AppUtil.isNetworkConnectionAvailable(this, true)){
 textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
else{
 Byron.setEnabled(false);
            Lennox.setEnabled(false);
            Skenners.setEnabled(false);
            Ballina.setEnabled(false);
}


}
```